# Print what subfolder is empty in all folders that contain the same subfolder?

Tags: python, glob

I have a folder A like this:

```
A>>(B,C,D)(subfolders)>>both B,C and D have folders 1,2,3 each.
```

in this case the subfolder '3' out of B,C and D happens to be empty.

How do you check and print which folder happens to be empty in all the folders
for example to make it search and print the number '3' since it is the only subfolder that is empty in all of the folders B,C and D?

Code I tried:

```
for i in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/A/**' ,recursive = True):
    if not os.listdir(i):
        print(f'{i} is empty everywhere' + '\n')
```

which isn't working.

All folders have the same subfolders (name) but some of them are empty. I need to find which are empty in all of those folders and print it.

Comment: So for clarification: All your directories (in this case `A, B, C`) have the same subdirectory and you only want to print the name of one subdirectory, if it is empty in all three directories? So if folder `3` would be empty in `A` and `B` but not in `C`, you don't want to print it?

Comment: Can the folder structure be hard coded in? In other words does it still need to work if you add a new folder 'E' or a new subfolder '4'?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly.

Comment: @webMan1 In the position of B,C,D would be many more but their subfolders would be the same number and names. Simply some of them would be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need two functions from the `os` module

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join
```

We need a starting point

```
dir = '/your/top/directory'
```

`walk` returns a generator, iterating on it at each step we have the path of the current directory, the list of directories and the list of files BUT we don't want to iterate and are interested *only* in the list of directories in the current directory, hence

```
dirs_l1 = next(walk(dir))[1]
```

note that, having to deal with a generator, the above is not too wasteful...

Now we have an inner loop on the subdirectories of level 1 (l1 sd, the sd contained in the root) to create a list of sets of directories of level 2, to be unpacked and passed to `set.intersection`, so that in `dirs_l2` we eventually have a set of all the directories of level 2 that are present in *every* directory of level 1

```
dirs_l2 = set.intersection(*[set(next(walk(join(dir, d)))[1]) for d in dirs_l1])
```

We make a loop on these inner directories, present in every l1 sd, and using the `all` builtin we check that, for every l1 sd all the l2 sd are  empty, in that case we print the name of the l2 subdirectory that is always empty

```
for d2 in dirs_l2:
    if all(next(walk(join(dir, d1, d2)))[1:] == ([],[]) for d1 in dirs_l1):
        print(d2)
```

---

*An example*

```
$ cat A.py
from os import walk
from os.path import join
dir = './A'
dirs_l1 = next(walk(dir))[1]
dirs_l2 = set.intersection(*[set(next(walk(join(dir, d)))[1]) for d in dirs_l1])
for d2 in dirs_l2:
    if all(next(walk(join(dir, d1, d2)))[1:] == ([], []) for d1 in dirs_l1): print(d2)
$ tree A
A
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── a
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── b
│   └── 3
├── B
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── a
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── b
│   └── 3
├── C
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── a
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── b
│   └── 3
└── D
    ├── 1
    │   └── a
    ├── 2
    │   └── b
    └── 3
$ python A.py 
3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution can think of right now is using a map, where the keys are folder names and the values could be booleans. `True` if empty everywhere, `False` otherwhise. Default would be `True`. So I would use:

```
all_empty_map = {}
for i in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/A**', recursive=True):
    cur_dir = os.path.basename(i)
    all_empty_map[cur_dir] = all_empty_map.get(cur_dir, True) and not os.listdir(i)

for cur_dir, isempty in all_empty_map.items():
    if isempty:
        print cur_dir
```

Of course, there may be things that can be optimized in the code.